# How do I tell backbone that the model is not new

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I have an object that's also saved in the server and I'm creating a Backbone model from that object.

But when I save the model, it's doing a PUT request, which is not what I want. How to tell Backbone that the data is already in the server without doing a fetch?

Comment: Backbone maps update requests to PUT http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync so what behavior do you expect?

Comment: I thought update requests were mapped to POST, but PUt was used to create a new item.

Comment: If someone wants to force a POST request, there are [multiple alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41091957/1218980).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Backbone determines the newness of a model by [checking if an id is set](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew) :

> **isNew** `model.isNew()`
>
> Has this model been saved to the server yet? If the model does not yet have an `id`, it is considered to be new.

And when you save a model,

- if it is new, a POST request will be emitted,
- if it is an update (an id has been set),  a PUT request will be sent

[Backbone Sync documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

---

And as noted by [@JayC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110103/how-do-i-tell-backbone-that-the-model-is-not-new#comment12954464_10110429) in the comments :

If there's an issue that the id can't literally be `id`, you can use [`idAttribute`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) to say which is the "identity" or key field.

Comment: Note, if there's an issue that the id can't literally be `id`, you can use idAttribute. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-idAttribute to say which is the "identity" or key field.

Comment: A question: I have a model which is new (no id), but it has other fields set in the front end. when I save the model, it's sending a PUT request. Shouldn't it send a POST request because there is no ID?

Comment: @archmage Strange, it should be a POST. Check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jq98Z/ , it reproduces the expected behavior. Maybe you overrode the default sync or the action mapping somewhere?

Comment: my model has a id even before saving it. but the isNew still works

Comment: @jlei Check if you have an idAttribute set or an isNew override. If not, please post a question

Answer (score -1):

Adding my two cents here, hope it avoids some hair pulling I had to do.

Setting a model's id property directly via constructor to false or null won't do the trick, you have to actually remove it from memory via via delete

For example, I just struggled to copy attributes from one model type to another type as a new model:

```
copy = Trip.clone()
#doesn't unset the id attribute
schedule = new models.Schedule(_.extend(copy.attributes, {id:null, trip_id:id})
#does unset the id attribute
delete schedule.id
schedule.save null, success: =>
  # back from POST vs PUT   
  ...
```